# main domain and sub-domain are promiscuous

Tags: apache, subdomain, lamp, linode

My site with the main domain name www.mysite.com works well before. (I use mysite to hide my actual domain name here). It's LAMP server in linode, set up with the guide http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/ubuntu-10.04-lucid .
I want to add sub.mysite.com for another virtual host on my host.
I follow http://davidpodley.com/2010/02/11/setting-up-subdomains-in-linode-and-apache/ and after I do

```
a2ensite sub.mysite.com
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

some users of www.mysite.com will access sub.mysite.com not www.mysite.com. 
I can found them in /srv/www/sub.mysite.com/logs/access.log and they tell me the problem. They should only access www.mysite.com. However, it works well on my PC.

### Why the users of www.mysite.com go to sub.mysite.com? Can anyone help me?

Some informations:

I added sub in A records 24 hours ago:
**My A Records is:**

```
Hostname IP Address TTL Options
         96.126.98.96    Default    Edit | Remove
sub      96.126.98.96    Default    Edit | Remove
mail     96.126.98.96    Default    Edit | Remove
www      96.126.98.96    Default    Edit | Remove
```

**my server's hostname is mysite, and my server's /etc/hosts is**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
96.126.98.96 mysite.mysite.com mysite
```

**apache2ctl -S:**

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com:10)
         port 443 namevhost mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com:10)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server sub.mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub.mysite.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost sub.mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub.mysite.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com:1)
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin mysite@gmail.com
     ServerName mysite.com
     ServerAlias www.mysite.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

     ServerAdmin mysite@gmail.com
     ServerName mysite.com
     ServerAlias www.mysite.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub.mysite.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin mysite@gmail.com
     ServerName sub.mysite.com
     ServerAlias www.sub.mysite.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/sub.mysite.com/public_html/
 #    DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite.com/public_html/sub
     ErrorLog /srv/www/sub.mysite.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/sub.mysite.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved.
Some users access my main domain site with IP directly. 
In apache2ctl -S result, we can see

```
default server sub.mysite.com
```

According apache explanation, the first  in the configuration file has the highest priority and can be seen as the default or primary server.
In my server, /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, rename mysite.com to 000mysite.com will make it be loaded before sub.mysite.com (in my site, "sub" is "f*")